# Relative references when form loads in AppData folder

Tags: vb.net, reference, relative-path

I've got a form that can be loaded from USB stick, from my home computer, or from work computers. The form executable is always stored in "*some path*\National Payroll\Build* and references a database in "*some path*\National Payroll".

The *some path* part changes, but the database is always in the parent directory. I've tried other advice to get the form's path, but I can only seem to get the path of the Local AppData folder where the form runs from when it is open, not the path of the form's executable. How do I get that?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Application.StartupPath
```

And, eventually `Application.StartupPath.Parent`

**EDIT: TEST REPORT**

Make a new project. Add a form with two `TextBoxes` named `StartupPath` and `ExecutablePath`. In the Form's Load event put the following code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    StartupPath.Text = Application.StartupPath
    ExecutablePath.Text = Application.ExecutablePath
End Sub
```

Compile and deploy the executable on a USB flash drive (or wherever you want) and double click. This output will be produced:
[image]

Comment: No luck, this is what I'm getting from Application.StartupPath:
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\HH0OX23A.ZJJ\O46NDK9E.J0N\payr..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0001_8f5e8a88557cdbef

Comment: Try with Applocation.ExecutablePath

Comment: Nope, same. I was down this route with another person on this same thread, but he deleted his comments, unfortunately.

Comment: Please see the edit. I added some test code, give it a try